# не могу убрать поля для оформления заказа woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Очень вас прошу мне помочь не получается убрать определённые поля при оформлении заказа в корзине (индекс, почта, область …)!

Пробовал разные плагины более 10, результат один и тот же, на плагине всё отключается но на странице ничего не работает.

Полностью переустанавливал WordPress и устанавливал всё заново с нуля но у меня почему-то не получается даже на любой теме отключить поля оформления заказа!

Как пример использовать данную тему “Woostify” отключить с помощью кода в (functions.php) так же не получилось!

Подскажите пожалуйста Может я что-то делаю не так и забыл какую-то банальную вещь!

Answer (score 0):

WC, как и ВП движется в сторону блоков и [страницы WC перешли на блочный редактор](https://woo.com/document/cart-checkout-blocks-status/).

Если нужно старое поведение - необходимо использовать шорткоды, как это было раньше.

Comment: Каким образом это позволит мне убрать лишние строки в оформлении заказа, то есть теперь должны заработать плагины или мне просто банально зайти в настройки темы там могу сделать всё необходимое?

Comment: @ITSchool Используй шотркоды и плагины. Читай по ссылке.